# Sending signal to pthread to abort sleeping

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

I'm have a pthread function, which sleeps most of the time using `usleep()`
I would like to send a signal from the main process to the thread to interrupt the sleeping sometimes.

The problem is that I can't find any reference of which signal exactly to send using `pthread_kill()`

the `usleep()` man page, states that `SIGALRM` should not be used together with `usleep()`

Do I need to use a specific signal, it doesn't matter ?

Comment: `usleep` returns with `EINTR` on every signal that's delivered to a thread/process. You'll probably be best off using `SIGUSR` signals. Also, `usleep` is now obsolete : consider using `nanosleep` instead. As an added bonus, you'll know how much sleep time was remaining at the time of the delivery of the signal.

Comment: Obligatory comment ["threads and signals don't mix well"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22threads+and+signals+don't+mix+well%22).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usleep` returns with `EINTR` on every signal that's delivered to a thread/process. You'll probably be best off using `SIGUSR` signals.

Also, `usleep` is now obsolete : consider using `nanosleep` instead. As an added bonus, you'll know how much sleep time was remaining at the time of the delivery of the signal.

Comment: I don't think that this a good strategy. Signal handling between threads is kind of tricky and not made for such fine grained control.

Answer (score 5):

The tools to synchronize between threads are not signals and `usleep` (or `nanosleep`) but combinations of `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`. Just have your thread wait on a condition (this can be done with a timeout) and have your `main` thread send a "signal" on the condition variable.

Comment: You're right, however, this is a legacy application I'm trying to add functionality to, I don't want to change the implementation of the thread.

Comment: sending signals to threads will cause you much trouble and headache. Don't do that if you can avoid. Signals are a tool between processes.